# Python Search list values in list of list

Tags: python, list

I have come across this:

```
searchTask = ["ST", "LOGIN", "BROWSE", "DOWNLOAD", "UPLOAD", "PING", "YOUTUBE", "FA", "BOOT"]
dateTime = "SCHEDULE: " + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H%M")) + "H"
finalList = []

for sublist in main_List:
    if dateTime in sublist:
       finalList.append(sublist[sublist.index(dateTime)])
       for x in searchTask:
           if x in sublist:
              finalList.append(sublist[sublist.index(x)])
```

Here's the value of `main_List`, it is a list that has a value of lists,

```
[['SCHEDULE: 1509H', 'SCHEDULE: 1404H', 'ST: 1500', 'PING: www.google.com'], ['SCHEDULE: 1509H', 'SCHEDULE: 1700H', 'SCHEDULE: 2001H', 'ST: 1169', 'FA']]
```

My problem is, how can I search the values of `searchTask` in `main_List` then append these values to `finalList` together with the scheduled time.
My `finalList` should look like this if printed for e.g:

```
finalList = [['SCHEDULE: 1509H', 'ST: 1500', 'PING: www.google.com' ],['SCHEDULE: 1509H', 'ST: 1169', 'FA']]
```

Comment: if the strings are identical you can use list.index(str) to find the first instance of the string

Comment: @Bugbeeb like this sir, `finalList.append(sublist[sublist.index(str(x))])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import datetime

main_List = [['SCHEDULE: 1509H', 'SCHEDULE: 1149H', 'ST: 1500', 'PING: www.google.com'], 
             ['SCHEDULE: 1509H', 'SCHEDULE: 1700H', 'SCHEDULE: 2001H', 'ST: 1169', 'FA']]

searchTask = ["ST", "LOGIN", "BROWSE", "DOWNLOAD", "UPLOAD", "PING", "YOUTUBE", "FA", "BOOT"]
dateTime = "SCHEDULE: " + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H%M")) + "H"
finalList = []

import re

pattern = "({}):".format("|".join(searchTask))
task_regex = re.compile(pattern)

for sublist in main_List:
    print dateTime
    if dateTime in sublist:
        finalList.append(dateTime)
        for e in sublist:
            if task_regex.search(e):
                finalList.append(e)
```

Comment: Thank sir, I just deleted the `:` in the pattern, because I'm not getting the `FA`  and `BOOT` since it has no `:` in the `main_List`. But overall the answer is correct. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is ok. But when the length of sublist is more than 10000, you should do something to reduce the cost time.